# Keycloak Identity Provider role sync

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak

I would like to map external openid-connect provider roles to my keycloak client roles.

In order to do this I have configured Identity Provider (in my case it's another Keycloak instance). Logging in to the main keycloak through the second instance works like a charm.

We have a requirement to assign roles in our server based on the external roles. In order to that I have configured for `Role mapper` of type `External role to role` for my Identity Provider. Works like a charm.

User John want to log in `Keycloak A`, goes to external IDP (`Keycloak B`). `Keycloak B` authenticates user and return JWT token with role `X`. My `Keycloak A` is configured to map role `X` to role `Y`.

The problem is that once `Keycloak B` administrator removes John from role `X` he can still log in through to my system (as intended) but role `Y` is not removed. Any chance to sync roles instead of only mapping it once?

Answer (score 4):

During the creation of the Role `Mapper External role to role` set the `Sync Mode Override` option to 'force' so that it always update the user during every login with the identity  provider.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak has `Sync` mode at various settings it offers i.e. mappers, client etc.
For your case as its Mapper you just have select Sync Mode to force.

Each time user logs in through keycloak its details are updated due to `force` sync mode.